# Can I installed debian i386 architecture on my intel core i3?

Tags: intel-core-i3

Im getting confuse about what to pick proper architecture on my system. I really didn't understand what is this.

Comment: i386 means its the 32-bit version of Debian. If you have less than 4gb of RAM this is the one to install.

Answer (score 2):

You can run i386 Debian on your I3, but unless you have a specific reason for doing it, you are better off running the x86_64 version - its there are virtually no disadvantages to running the x86_64 version, but a number of advantages, including

- Easy support for more then 4 gigs of RAM (although i386 can do this
  also if you install a PAE kernel)
- Allows you to do more with virtual servers - KVM, for example, really
  needs to be installed on an X86_64 install
- x86 supports 386 programs, but the reverse is not true.

The 386 architecture is really around for very old PC's (This change occurred around the time of the Pentium 4 for most people)

Comment: i386 predates Pentium 4 by several architectures and nearly a decade.  Its tricky because i386 was on the market for nearly half that time by the looks like it.

Comment: Debian doesn't have an "x86 version" separate from the i386 version.  It has "i386" (32-bit) and "amd64" (64-bit).  It sounds like you're actually talking about amd64, but calling it "x86" instead, which is incorrect.  Depending on context, "x86" sometimes refers specifically to 32-bit systems, and sometimes means any 32-bit or 64-bit Intel-compatible system, but it never means 64-bit specifically.

Comment: The name that linux distros use is x86_64, tho internally its AMD64 I believe. I've edited your answer to match. I'd also add that itanium was *supposed* to be the 64 bit intel arch, it was a flop, and intel licenced 64 bit extensions to the x64 arch from AMD, as EMT64 amongst other names. The first intel processor that would support this is waaaay back from '04 so its been around a while.

Comment: x86 is a 32-bit architecture.  As pointed out Intel licensed the 64-bit extension to the x86 architecture from AMD.  Thus ALL 64-bit Intel CPUs are based on the x86 architecture commonly known as x86-64 though commercially sold as EMT64.